# Node.js fetch pdf upload with multipart/form-data

Tags: node.js, fetch-api, multipartform-data, supabase

I am bashing my head against the wall here...
I am trying to upload a pdf to supabase storage bucket.
My code is working with jpg but not with a pdf. I am suspecting it has something to do with the encoding but I can't get it to work.

I am using next.js 13 if that is important.

In my index.js I have a file upload form:

```
async function uploadFile(ev) {
    
    if (ev.target.files.length > 0) {
      
      const files = ev.target.files;
      const data = new FormData();
      for (const file of files) {
        data.append('file', file);
      }
      
      fetch('/api/upload/', {
        method: "POST",
        body: data
      })
      
    }
}
```

```
<label htmlFor="myfile" name="myfile" style={{ "width": "24px", "height": "24px" }}>
        <input type="file" id="myFile" onChange={uploadFile}/>
</label>
```

in pages/api/upload.js

```
import { createClient } from '@supabase/supabase-js'
import multiparty from 'multiparty';
import fs from 'fs'
import mime from 'mime-types'
import crypto from 'crypto'

export default function handler(req, res) {
    
    const form = new multiparty.Form()
    
    console.log("I am the handler function")

    form.parse(req, async function (err, fields, files) {
    
        console.log(err)
        console.log(fields)
        console.log(files)

        // extract the file-type
        const fileExtension = files.file[0].originalFilename.split('.').pop();
        // generate random filename
        const fileName = crypto.randomUUID();
        // read in the file content
        const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(files.file[0].path)
  
        
        const { data, error } = await supabase.storage.from("mybucket")
            .upload(fileName+"."+fileExtension,
                fileContent,
                { contentType: mime.lookup(files.file[0].path) }
        );
        
    })

    res.json("OK")
}
```

The issue is that this functions works absolutely fine with jpgs and text files but not with pdfs.

If I send a pdf it goes into the handler function but form.parse() just does nothing - throws no error, reads no file - nothing.

multiparty.Form() supposedly has an `encoding` options which I tried setting to "binary" but I don't know what you can actually set it to since there is nothing in the docs.

Comment: "multipart" is not "multiparty".

Comment: ...what is this `multiparty` library you're using and why do you think you need it? And where are you using `fetch`?

Comment: I am using fetch in index.js so when the user selects a file its automatically uploaded. multiparty is a library to parse form data https://github.com/pillarjs/multiparty#readme

Comment: When you upload a pdf file to the handler, does it at least return the `ok` response, or does it hang until timeout?